# Delphi unit automatically gets added to uses in Seattle

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle, firedac, datamodule

In my Firemonkey multi device project the IDE keeps adding the unit "FireDAC.VCLUI.Wait" to my uses in a data module of my project.
This unit keeps me from building the project, because it can't resolve the name in Android or iOS. The strange thing is that it previously didn't do this and I haven't added/changed anything to this data module.

I know some component add units to the uses but as I said it's a firemonkey project not a VCL project so it shouldn't add this.

How can I keep the IDE from adding this unit?

Comment: Does this happen when you start a brand new project? What happens when you one by one remove installed packages?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Place a [`IFDGUIxWaitCursor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.UI.TFDGUIxWaitCursor) component on your data module and set its [`Provider`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FireDAC.Comp.UI.TFDGUIxComponent.Provider) property to `'FMX'` (FireMonkey).

Remove that unit from the uses section, so the IDE will now set the one corresponding to Firemonkey instead of VCL.

> Note: If the Provider property changes its value, then developers need
> to delete the implementation units for the old Provider value from the
> uses sections. For example, switching from 'Forms' to 'FMX' requires
> to delete the TFDGUIxFormsXxx units.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the "Provider" property to "Console", if you compile it for Linux.